# How to handle large select lists in content types?

Tags: entities, nodes

I need to add a city field for a content type in D7. I'm getting it from a federal census table and it's going to be around 35K+ records. Any thoughts on filtering this list down by state and/or county? Without some kind of filtering, I'm afraid I'll bring Drupal to it's knees. BTW, I can't just use a taxonomy list because I need to key the list on a city ID. I also will have county ID info. So, I really need to filter the counties list to just those for the state the user has selected, then the cities by that county.

Here's the general structure:
User selects
   State ->  County-> ->Cities.

I tried looking at the references module but the reference field I created didn't seem to be filterable.

Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: you need ajaxable dropdown list for countries

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a perfect job for [Simple hierarchical select](http://drupal.org/project/shs)

> Simple hierarchical select defines a new form widget for taxonomy fields to select a term by "browsing" through the vocabularies hierarchy.
>
> The widget is available in node forms and as Views exposed filter.

You can add your locations as a hierarchical taxonomy, and SHS will AJAX-load child terms into a new inline select, then children of those in a new select, and so on. Something like

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but the issue with this tool is that it's using taxonomies. I need to import my lists with a key (e.g.: fips_city, city_name), but typically, taxonomy terms don't have multiple fields, just a term name. The reason for doing this is there are duplicate city names, but fips_city is a unique field, already stored in the related table data (which I'm importing in a feed), and I need to link that data to this data via the fips_city field. Any thoughts on doing that?

Comment: _"taxonomy terms don't have multiple fields, just a term name."_...in Drupal 6 that might have been true, but in Drupal 7 taxonomy terms are entities and just as fieldable as nodes. Contrib modules are written to extend core functionality, unfortunately they're very unlikely to match a use case that doesn't use Drupal's core elements. Just from a design perspective, you don't _need_ to key the relationship on a city ID, it sounds like you'd just prefer to keep things that way. The parent/child term relationship offered by Drupal core is just as good, and will allow you to use contrib modules

Comment: Clive, I realize I can use custom fields for the vocabulary type and can store the information this way. I was trying to use a node reference for the sake of having more advantages of storing the lists in an actual node, but I think your suggestion is probably a good one if I can successfully migrate my data to test it. Thanks!